# Python Input to Multi Theft Auto Not Working

Tags: python, bots

I am attempting to send input from python to the game Multi Theft Auto to automate an action. I am able to run the script and get input in steam games (skyrim and elden ring both tested) as well as bloons tower defense and various other applications. Additionally, I am able to get input on the Multi Theft Auto Client in the server browser but not once I am connected to a server. Once I am connected to a server there is no input whatsoever from the script.

I have attempted to solve this problem with pydirectinput, using ctypes, and running my ide (visual studio code) as administrator as well as the game as administrator already. I have also read everything I have been able to find so far on the topic and I am really lost. Any help would be appreciated. The current implementation that I used from multiple sources is below:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import pydirectinput

import ctypes
import time
import sys

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput
def elevate(console=True):
    arg = 'forced_elevate'
    if sys.argv[-1] != arg and not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        params = u' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [arg])
        ret = ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u'runas', unicode(sys.executable), params, None, 5 if console else 0)
        if int(ret) > 32:
            sys.exit(0)
elevate()
# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

# directx scan codes http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
while (True):
    PressKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
    ReleaseKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: MANY games implement much more sophisticated anti-cheating strategies when you're connected to a server and your cheating can affect other players.  They'll often bypass the input system and go straight to the hardware drivers.

Comment: I would try pywinauto.

Comment: @user2679290 I tried that just now with the exact same result as before. Inputs could be sent anywhere except in game when connected to a server. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @TimRoberts I explicitly asked server administrators if I was allowed to use automation and they said it would be fine so my "cheating" isn't cheating nor is it something that would even affect other players as I am automating a solo player minigame.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm pretty confident you are being foiled by anti-cheating technology, and those folks have invested heavily into making that robust.  I do not like your chances.

Comment: Try reversing it, if you have the know-how.